# hybrid cable for QSFP to CX4 convertion

Tags: networking, switch, cable, 10gbethernet

here is a hybrid cable for QSFP to CX4. Will this fit SFP+ ports? Deeply confused by standards and struck in a situation with wrong hardware selection!Personally have not seen the ports/hardware and hence the obviously stupid question! thanks for stopping by and bearing with me.

http://www.cablesondemand.com/pcategory/72/category/QSFP+-+CX4/URvars/Catalog/Library/InfoManage/QSFP_TO_CX4_COPPER_CABLES.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFP+ looks like [this](http://www.siemon.com/sis/store/cca_sfp+-copper-cable-assemblies.asp). And this would not fit neither the QSFP nor the CX4 connectors.

QSFP looks like [this](http://tmcscsi.com/images/qsfp.JPG).
CX4 like [this](http://www.sierra-cables.com/Cables/images/4X-Infiniband-L.jpg).